# World's Greatest Util methods

Tags: discussion

For those of us who are regular contributors (especially on the Apex side), we've all benefited from the contributions of others to improve our own game.

As such, from time-to-time, I've grabbed posted code snippets and added (or adapted) into my own `Util` class to maximize my productivity.

The question at hand is -- where can we post into a common `Community-wide` place our own 'personal favorite' short-concise `Util` methods (or links to said same) so we can all benefit?  Even a running list here in Meta would be more than adequate.

For example, this is one I borrowed and adapted from @sfdcfox that is incredibly useful to me.

**Without the method (and so often seen in OPs) -- tedious bulkification code**

```
set<ID> aIdSet = new set<ID>();
for (Contact c : Trigger.new)
    aIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
map<ID,Account> aIdToAccountMap = new map<ID,Account> (
              [select id, name from Account where id IN :aIdSet]);
```

**With the method - one line of code!**

```
map<ID,Account> aIdToAccountMap = new map<ID,Account> (
              [select id, name from Account 
                  where id IN :Util.getIdSetFromField(Trigger.new,Contact.AccountId)]);
```

**The Util method(s)**

```
// ---------------------------------
// getIdSetFromField : returns set of IDs from a field of type ID in a list of sobjects
// ---------------------------------
public static Set<ID> getIdSetFromField(SObject[] records, SObjectField fieldname) {
    return new Set<ID> ((List<ID>) getValListFromField(List<ID>.class, records, fieldname));
}

//  --------------------------------------------------------
//  getValListFromField : Returns a list of field values from a list of sobjects; 
//                        ref: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/64949/2602
//   Usage Ex: Decimal[] amountList = (Decimal[])Util.getValListFromField(Decimal[].class,
//                                                                        Trigger.new,
//                                                                        Opportunity.Amount);
//  --------------------------------------------------------
public static Object[] getValListFromField(Type resListType, SObject[] records, SObjectField fieldname) {
    Object[] res    = (Object[])resListType.newInstance();
    for (SObject sObj: records)
        res.add(sobj.get(fieldname));
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: Oof, that `getIdSetFromField` method has got to be way slower than `Map<Id, SObject>(...).keySet()`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I'm not following you with the contents of `(...)` please elaborate

Comment: It would just be `new Map<Id, SObject>(records).keySet()`. I guess it was a little silly to shorten.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I must be missing something - but how does that extract a set of `AccountIds` from a list of `Contacts`

Comment: Well, not for lookup fields I suppose. The comparison doesn't work there.

Comment: Also, I could use some more ideas for the open-source/managed library I am working on :p

Comment: @sfdcfox -- well, one could argue that if the Open Source library was called `sfdcfox`, it would show up a lot in Google and hence might address my desire to have a one stop shop :-)

Comment: Always had this question.. we should have wiki for all such amazing API or tips that will help improve the programming standard of newbies like us and make us reach prod faster.

Googling for such leads to blogs with MCQ . This will help.

Comment: @AdrianLarson here's an example of another discussion/opinionated post that lives and thrives in meta

Answer (score 14):

Open source it. If you're willing to share it with the world, **[GitHub](https://github.com)** is a great option.

I've shared a couple there I'm fairly proud of (though they're not necessarily a finished product):

- [SObjectFactory](https://github.com/aalarson/SObjectFactory)
- [DML](https://github.com/aalarson/DML)

Also, some of my favorite third-party tools are on there and actually have install links:

- [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector)
- [Declarative Rollup Lookup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

I have a couple where I didn't come up with the idea and don't want to share someone else's work, but the names and a skeleton can tell you a fair amount. That's all I needed to build it from scratch: [Pluck](https://gist.github.com/aalarson/dc2f313083a11a919a02549ff8ffff67) and [GroupBy](https://gist.github.com/aalarson/d8e3c88f7b6648e98395d1d71bbe75fa) (gists are great, too).

Comment: yes - I get that -- but how would the community know where to look?  It took me by chance to discover yours - and DLRS gets mentioned a ton because it solves a large problem

Comment: I think that for new comers to Salesforce knowing where resources are on GitHub would be an issue as they wouldn't know users names to be searching for.

Answer (score 6):

Since you seem to have a passion for this @cropredy, I would suggest that either you or "a trusted volunteer" (a mod perhaps?) open a new Github repository under the name of "SalesforceStackExchangeForum" (or similar) to which users can either contribute their code, or provide links to their own repositories. A Gist of the same name would seem appropriate to create as well.

I'd hope we'd have no issues providing a prominent link to it from our site, but would expect one of the mods would need to speak with management to make that happen. I'd also hope we'd have no issues with using the the forum's name on Github but recommend we ask permission from StackExchange to use the forum's name first.

It's possible they may want to open it and/or control it (doubtful, but you never know). If that should happen and we decide that's not how we want to do it, then obviously we can use some acronym that's similar enough to convey this Forum's association with the repository without violating anyone's copyrights.

Comment: Seems a good idea.

Comment: It would fit within documentation on `Apex`, perhaps, if that feature is ever rolled out here.

Comment: would love to contribute to an SFSE helper index

Answer (score 5):

Well I will list down some of API's that I have used.

1. [ESAPI](https://github.com/forcedotcom/force-dot-com-esapi) - For Handling FLS in Apex.
2. [Apex MDAPI](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) - Metadata features in Apex.
3. [Salesforce Test Data Generator](https://github.com/mbotos/SmartFactory-for-Force.com) - Quickly Generate Lookups, Master-Detail      Relationships, and Required Fields
4. [FinancialForce Apex Common](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common)- Application Enterprise Patterns on Force.com
5. [Apex Tooling API](http://%20https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi).

Answer (score 0):

I'm throwing in my library to the pool :)
https://github.com/amorek/sfdc-toolkit